# 64bit unsigned Subtraction issue

Tags: c++, 64-bit, subtraction

So, I have the following-

```
size_t Num2= 2359198081
size_t Num1= 2359197799

size_t Diff= Num2 - Num1;
```

if I do,

```
std::cout << "Diff: " << Diff;
```

I get,

```
Diff: 18446744071938113404
```

If i do int64_t instead of size_t then as expected I get a negative value since Num2 and Num1 are bigger than 2 raise to 32

If I do,

```
std::cout << "Diff: " << Num2 - Num1 << std::endl;
```

Then I get,

Diff: 282

which is as expected.

What am I doing incorrect here? rather how can i get this to do a correct 64bit subtraction?

Comment: Show real code. What you're describing doesn't make sense, so there must be something going on that you haven't mentioned. Provide a program that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type. If you're expecting a negative value, adjust your expectations. And show real code; with what you've shown, `Num2 - Num1` yields 282. Are you perhaps computing `Num1 - Num2`? Read this: [mcve]

Comment: How can you get a negative value using `unsigned` integers?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: OP is using `int64_t` in that scenario.

Comment: Next time use copy/paste to put your code into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your code as asked by other in comments (sorry couldn't comment due to 50+ rep requirement). Since `size_t` is `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`, the subtraction should yield 282, unless you're using a machine/compilation system which implements`unsigned int` shorter than 32-bits.

I tried this and it works correctly (64-bit). Since `Diff` in your case is printing out `0xFFFFFFFF966A0000`, I guess you're using a 64-bit implementation on `size_t` as well. More can be said only if you post your full code!

Comment: Stupid rule. Have your 50.

Comment: Yay! Let's comment! Thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you meant to say `Diff = Num2 - Num1` But you accidentally said `Diff = Num1 - Num2`:

```
size_t Num2= 2359198081;
size_t Num1= 2359197799;
size_t Diff = Num1 - Num2;
std::cout << Diff << std::endl;
```

prints:

> 18446744073709551334

Which is what you're getting. Well, you claim you're getting `18446744071938113404`, which is slightly different, so I'm guessing your actual numbers are different and your question is not accurate.

```
size_t num2 = 2359198081;
size_t num1 = 2359197799;
size_t diff = num2 - num1;
std::cout << diff << std::endl;
```

prints:

> 282

Which is what you want.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11e78778837024f7)